# Is there any method/function that is related to skip in foreach using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I am doing a project in codeigniter 3.3(latest version). Is there any method/function that is related to skip while inside the foreach? For example, I have 5 data in my table(ofcourse you need to use foreach in view to get all the data). The 3 images will be display on the top part and the last 2 will be display in the bottom part, is it possible

**View**

```
<div class="container-fluid proj-bottom">
            <div class="row">
                 <?php foreach($getContent  as $content){ if($content->id=="1"){ skip();}?>
                 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fh5co-project animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                    <?=$content->id?>
                    <a href="#fly" data-toggle="modal" data-animation="animated zoomInRight" ><img src="<?= base_url() .'uploaded/'. $content->img_path?>" alt="Free HTML5 Website Template by FreeHTML5.co" class="img-responsive">  

                   <h3>Fly</h3>
                        <span>View</span>
                    </a>
                 </div>
                 <?php } ?>

            </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: split the array and foreach twice

Comment: Can you give me an example where/how should I do that?

Comment: Can't it be only PHP `continue`? Try this: `<?php foreach($getContent  as $content){ if($content->id=="1"){ continue;}?>`

Comment: I dont know that continue is exist in php lol.. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `continue`:

```
<div class="container-fluid proj-bottom">
            <div class="row">
                 <?php foreach($getContent  as $content){ if($content->id=="1"){ skip();}?>
                 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fh5co-project animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                    <?=$content->id?>
                    <a href="#fly" data-toggle="modal" data-animation="animated zoomInRight" ><img src="<?= base_url() .'uploaded/'. $content->img_path?>" alt="Free HTML5 Website Template by FreeHTML5.co" class="img-responsive">  

                   <h3>Fly</h3>
                        <span>View</span>
                    </a>
                 </div>
                 <?php } ?>

            </div>
  </div>
```

The `continue` ([Manual reference](http://php.net/continue)) will skip the current loop and go for the next record if it exists.

The `break` ([Manual reference](http://php.net/break)) will skip and quit the loop.

Comment: You're welcome. As you said you didn't know about the `continue` I presume you're learning PHP so I'll recommend you reading [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com) and of course the [PHP Manual](http://nz2.php.net/manual/en/index.php) (there is [PT-BR](http://nz2.php.net/manual/pt_BR/index.php) version if you prefer)